# How can I get the grey background in the outer div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make my grey background show until the bottom border :

```
 .grey {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
  }
 .itemsheight {
    height: 97px
  }
```

Here is the html:

```
 <div className="row border itemsheight">
            <div className="col-md-8 desc space">{name} channel package</div>
            <div className="col-md-2 desc grey"></div>
            <div className="col-md-2 dollar grey price middle space">{price}</div>
 </div>
```

How can I stretch the background color in the last column until the bottom?

Look here also:http://codepen.io/gekkerkanniet/pen/dOKLdG

Comment: if you want price div height until bottom, you can just give your price div height: 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have setup itemsheight to 97px,
so itemsheight's child can use percentage to set their height

```css
/*************Cart******************/
.cart .pad {
  padding: 2px;
}
.cart .padheader {
  padding: 17px;
}
.cart .links {
  padding: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.cart .border {
  border: solid 0.5px;
}
.cart .right {
  text-align: right;
}
.cart .costs {
  padding: 2px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.cart .medium {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 53px;
}
.cart .small {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.cart .itemsheaderheight {
  height: 68px;
}
.cart .itemsheight {
  height: 97px;
}
.cart .space {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}
.cart .grey {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
.cart .yourorder {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: left;
  color: #333333;
}
.cart .price {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.cart .desc {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.cart .border-bottom {
  border-bottom: lightgray solid 0.5px;
}
.cart .border-top {
  border-top: lightgray solid 0.5px;
}
.cart .collapse {
  display: none;
}
.cart .collapse.in {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart">
    <div class="row border itemsheight">
        <div class="col-md-8 desc space"><!-- react-text: 140 -->Entertainment Plus<!-- /react-text -->
            <!-- react-text: 141 --> channel package<!-- /react-text --></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 desc grey"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 dollar grey price middle space">10</div>
        <div class="links"><a href="">Change</a><!-- react-text: 146 --> | <!-- /react-text --><a href="">Remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```